# Grading Schema: 2D array and printing the average

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am incredibly new to java and my teacher gave us this assignment with the idea we can look online for how to get the code to work. I am feeling so lost because I only worked with arrays once and double arrays only once. I could really use some help and explanation on how I am to go about getting this program to run.

So far my teacher has showed me how to split up the students and the grades, however he did not show me how to print the grades. Also how do I calculate the average with just the rows and not the columns for each student when you have a double array?

Grading Schema: In a separate function, you will implement a grading schema. Write a
program that reads a student’s name together with his or her test score from a file given by the user.
The first two values in the file will represent the number of students followed by the number of tests.
The program should then compute the average test score for each student and assign the appropriate
grade (A, B, C, D, E or F) as well as the average of each test. Your program must perform the following
functions.
a) A void function calculateAverage, to determine the average of the test scores for each student.

Heres the txt file:

Tom 91 67 84 50 69

Suzy 74 78 58 62 64

Peter 55 95 81 77 61

Paul 91 95 92 77 86

Diane 91 54 52 53 92

Emily 82 71 66 68 95

Natalie 97 76 71 88 69

Ben 62 67 99 85 94

Mark 53 61 72 83 73

Anna 64 91 61 53 68

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Grades {



private static final String FILENAME2 = "/Users/Jarvis/Documents/Students.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {

        fr = new FileReader(FILENAME2);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String students [] = new String[10];
        int [][] grades = new int [10][5];
        String[] words;
        String sCurrentLine;
        int counter=0;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME2));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            words = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
            students[counter]=words[0];
            System.out.print(students[0]+ " ");

            for (int i=1; i < words.length; i++){
               grades[counter][i-1]=Integer.parseInt(words[i]);

            } //end of outer for loop


            System.out.println();

        } // end of while loop



         } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}//end of main

public static void calculateAverage (int grade [][]){

    int temp;
    int sum;


} // end of calculateAverage()
```

Comment: counter should be counter++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add `counter++;` at the bottom of your loop.

As for averaging, this will calculate the average of each student's grades (assuming this format `grade[student][grade]`) than print the student's number `grade[student]` followed by their average grade `grades.get();`.

```
public static void calculateAverage (int grade[][]){

    ArrayList<Double> averageGrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int sum = 0;

    for(int student = 0; student < grade.length; student++){
    for(int i = 0; i < grade[student].length; i++){

        if(i == 0){
            sum = grade[student][i];
        }else if(i == grade[student].length - 1){

            sum += grade[student][i]; //Add next grade to sum

            averageGrades.add((double) (sum/i)); //Divide the sum by the number of grades (average)

        }else{

        sum += grade[student][i]; //Add next grade to sum

        }

    }
}

    for(int counter = 0; counter < averageGrades.size(); counter++){
        //Cycle through the grades and print them after the student name (grade[counter])
        System.out.println(grade[counter] + " " + averageGrades.get(counter));

    }



  }
```